# Either segmentation fault 11 or (-215) N >= K

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to create a Bag of visual Words program, but I am running into an issue. Every time I run the program, I either get a `segmentation fault: 11` error, or if I change the dictSize variable I get a `error: (-215) N >= K in function kmeans`. I have tried resizing the images, using different ones but nothing seems to help. Here is what I have up to now:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {

    //=================================== LEARN ===================================

    struct dirent *de = NULL;
    DIR *d = NULL;
    d = opendir(argv[1]);
    if(d == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't open directory");
        return(2);
    }

    Mat input;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    Mat descriptor;
    Mat featuresUnclustered;
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> detector = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();


    while((de = readdir(d))){
          if ((strcmp(de->d_name,".") != 0) && (strcmp(de->d_name,"..") != 0)  && (strcmp(de->d_name,".DS_Store") != 0)) {

            char fullPath[] = "./";
            strcat(fullPath, argv[1]);
            strcat(fullPath, de->d_name);
            printf("Current File: %s\n",fullPath);

            input = imread(fullPath,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            cout << "Img size => x: " << input.size().width << ", y: " << input.size().height << endl;
            // If the incoming frame is too big, resize it
            if (input.size().width > 3000) {
                double ratio = (3000.0)/(double)input.size().width;
                resize(input, input, cvSize(0, 0), ratio, ratio); 
                cout << "New size => x: " << input.size().width << ", y: " << input.size().height << endl;
            }

            detector->detect(input, keypoints);
            detector->compute(input, keypoints, descriptor);
            featuresUnclustered.push_back(descriptor);
        }
    }

    closedir(d);

    int dictSize = 200;
    TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.001);
    int retries = 1;
    int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
    BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictSize,tc,retries,flags);
    Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster(featuresUnclustered);
    FileStorage fs("dict.yml",FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "vocabulary" << dictionary;
    fs.release();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    char fullPath[] = "./";
    strcat(fullPath, argv[1]);
    strcat(fullPath, de->d_name);
```

That part of your code is a serious bug (undefined behavior, but seg fault most likely).
strcat does **not** allocate any extra space for the concatenation.  It only overwrites whatever follows the terminating null in the first string.
Your `fullPath` is allocated with just enough space for the initial 2 characters plus terminating null.  Whatever follows that terminating null may be memory belonging to some other part of your program.

If you know the maximum file path length for your OS, you can use the crude correction of putting that max plus 2 as a number (or named constant) between the [] in the declaration of fullPath.

The less crude correction is to compute the required lenth of the string you want to build and malloc that much space (be sure to count the terminating null) and combine the three strings there.

Comment: The above answer focused only on the seg fault that seems to be the focus of the original question.  There is more that I would consider to be "wrong" with the original code, such as the idea of prepending "./" to the specified directory.  My suggestions on fixing **how** you do that should not be viewed as endorsing the idea that you should do that.  I'm not trying to rewrite your whole program better.

Comment: Also, your manipulation of C strings in C++ code is unwise.  While my answer focused on eliminating the seg fault from the misuse of C strings, your better choice would be to reduce your use of C strings.  Convert C strings to std::string before manipulating them and then access the std::string as a C string after manipulation, when you need it to be a C string again.

Comment: Hey JSF, as you might have noticed I am a complete novice in C++. I have corrected the things you have pointed out, but it has not solved my problem. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: I prefer not to look past the obvious cause of a seg fault when giving an answer on the cause of a seg fault.  If you have corrected the error and the code still fails, I think it is OK to edit your question to contain the corrected code and current symptoms (if the symptoms have changed).  If there is another, less obvious, cause for a seg fault, someone would likely spot that once you post code without the obvious cause.